# How to convert a JSON string into an array (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, object

using the below code for decoding json

```
$categories = json_decode($data);
$categories = $categories->data;
```

where i get this

```
{"categories":[{"id":1,"name":"Utilities","apps":897,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/uti.jpg"},{"id":2,"name":"Productivity","apps":477,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/pro.jpg"},{"id":3,"name":"Music","apps":466,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/mus.jpg"},{"id":4,"name":"Travel","apps":289,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/tra.jpg"},{"id":5,"name":"Navigation","apps":297,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/nav.jpg"},{"id":6,"name":"Books","apps":271,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/boo.jpg"},{"id":7,"name":"Healthcare & Fitness","apps":250,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/hea.jpg"},{"id":8,"name":"Games","apps":5116,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/gam.jpg"},{"id":9,"name":"Social Networking","apps":272,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/soc.jpg"},{"id":10,"name":"Lifestyle","apps":434,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/lif.jpg"},{"id":11,"name":"Finance","apps":200,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/fin.jpg"},{"id":12,"name":"News","apps":128,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/new.jpg"},{"id":13,"name":"Photography","apps":481,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/pho.jpg"},{"id":14,"name":"Entertainment","apps":1251,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/ent.jpg"},{"id":15,"name":"Business","apps":221,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/bus.jpg"},{"id":16,"name":"Sports","apps":199,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/spo.jpg"},{"id":17,"name":"Education","apps":433,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/edu.jpg"},{"id":18,"name":"Medical","apps":262,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/med.jpg"},{"id":19,"name":"Weather","apps":64,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/wea.jpg"},{"id":20,"name":"Reference","apps":419,"iconurl":"http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/ref.jpg"}]}
```

and i would like to convert to in an array  like this

```
Array[0]
    {
       id => 1
       name => Utilities
       apps => 897
       iconurl => http:\/\/static.apptrackr.org\/caticons\/uti.jpg
    }
```

and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a [JSON string](http://json.org/). You can use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it into a PHP variable, e.g.

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
print_r($obj->categories); // array of StdClass objects
```

You can access and iterate the categories array regularly

```
echo $obj->categories[0]->name; // Utilities
echo $obj->categories[1]->name; // Productivity
echo $obj->categories[2]->name; // Music
```

To convert the StdClass objects to arrays, you could do

```
$categories = array();
foreach (json_decode($json)->categories as $category) {
    $categories[] = (array) $category;
}
print_r($categories);
```

You could also do it with a [lambda function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
// Before PHP5.3
$categories = array_map(
    create_function('$el', 'return (array) $el;'), 
    json_decode($json)->categories);

// After PHP5.3
$categories = array_map(
    function($el) { return (array) $el; }, 
    json_decode($json)->categories);
```

Comment: sorry for not declaring this but to get this i used 

$categories = json_decode($data);
$categories = $categories->data;

where i got the result above

and when i try using your code i get error on foreach

thanks for the help

Comment: @Mahmoud There is no `$categories->data` in the object string you gave. What's the error you get?

Comment: here is a link for a print_r(json_decode($categories)); http://pastie.org/844979 the one in my question is after i used $categories = $categories->data; the error i get in foreach ($arr->categories as $category) {

Comment: @Mahmoud I'm not sure to understand what you are doing there, but will `json_decode($categories)` with `$categories` being derived from your `$categories = json_decode($data); $categories = $categories->data;` work? Apparently you have an object containing a JSON string in `data`.

Comment: sorry my mistake i have updated my question where you can see and understand what i have done and here is the full code http://pastie.org/845028 where you can see and teach me what i am doing worng thanks again i appricate helping me

Comment: Like I said, `data` contains a JSON string you will need to decode too to convert it to an object. See pasty.

Answer (score 1):

Erm, you can just set the 2nd parameter to convert JSON into an array instead of into an object:

```
$categories = json_decode($data, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at get_object_vars
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon seems correct - that looks like JSON.  Assuming, though, that you're dealing with an "actual" PHP Object, then it will be iterable; simply run through it with a `foreach` and push each key/value pair into your destination array.